# Spring Cloud Config Client with @RefreshScope not applying

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have a config server and client up and running by means of Spring Cloud. However I am not able to dynamically update the properties on my @Component

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("threads-config")
@RefreshScope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.DEFAULT)
internal class ThreadConfig {

  var numThreads = 1

  var pollInterval = 1

}
```

My application.properties look like the following:

```
spring.application.name=my-backend
spring.config.import =optional:configserver:hhtp://localhost:8888
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

Comment: What does your config server configuration look like? How are you trying to dynamically refresh those properties?

Comment: server.port = 8888

spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///C:/Users/212/Documents/GitHub/config-properties

spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=master

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a properties file or yml file with you clint app name to be able to refresh configuration files.

For example, if your client application has name **test-client** like

```
spring.application.name=test-client
```

Then you need to create a configuration file with the same name. test-client or **test-client.yml**